# if and elseif condition in PHP

Tags: php

If I select fruit and mix fruit it will show a`lert "You have selected Fruit's favour and Fruit's topping, are you sure?"`
but my code it show `"You have selected chocolate's favour and chocolate's topping, are you sure?"`

It wont go to else.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if($favour=="Chocolate"and $topping=="Chocolate Chip"){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(window.confirm("You have selected chocolate's favour and chocolate's topping, are you sure?")) { alert("You have apply successfully");window.location="index.php";
            } else {
                window.location="customization.php";
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    elseif($favour=="Fruit"and $topping=="Mix Fruit"){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(window.confirm("You have selected Fruit's favour and Fruit's topping, are you sure?")) { alert("You have apply successfully");window.location="index.php";
            } else {
                window.location="customization.php";
            }
        </script>
    <?php
    }
else{
    $cakesize=$_POST['cakesize'];

    $favour=$_POST['favour'];
    $topping=$_POST['topping'];
    $color=$_POST['color'];
    $cmessage=$_POST['cmessage'];
    $cumessage=$_POST['customize_message'];
    $date=date("Y-m-d");
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("You have apply successfully");
        window.location = "index.php"
    </script>
    <?php

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO customization (cakesize,cfavour,topping, ccolor, cmessage,customizeMessage, C_date, Member_ID,status) VALUES ('$cakesize','$favour' ,'$topping', '$color' ,'$cmessage','$cumessage', '$date', '$uname','pending')");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When checking conditions, you need to use a equality operator: `==`

```
$favour=$_POST['favour'];
$topping=$_POST['topping'];

if($favour=="Chocolate"and $topping=="Chocolate Chip"){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(window.confirm("You have selected chocolate's favour and chocolate's topping, are you sure?")) { alert("You have apply successfully");window.location="index.php";
        } else {
            window.location="customization.php";
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

You also need to make sure the variables you are checking are set to a value **before** you check them. I've edited the above code to reflect this.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed is that you aren't setting `$favour` or `$topping` before checking them. You need to do this first, otherwise you will just be checking against variables initialized without a value.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing `=` instead of `==`.